# Double Integral $\int\limits_0^1\int\limits_0^{1-x}(y-2x)^{2}\sqrt{x+y}\,dy\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

Good night, i have a serious problem changing the integration limits, i read two books but i don't understand, i put an example...
$$\int_0^1\int_0^{1-x}(y-2x)^{2}\sqrt{x+y}\,dy\,dx$$
I use the change: 
$\begin{cases}
u=x+y\\
v=y-2x
\end{cases}$

Then:
$\begin{cases}
x=\frac{u}{3}-\frac{v}{3}\\
y=\frac{2u}{3}-\frac{v}{3}
\end{cases}$

And evaluating:
$\begin{cases}
y+x=1\rightarrow u=1\\
y=0\rightarrow2u=-v\\
x=0\rightarrow u=v\\
x=1\rightarrow v=-3+u
\end{cases}$

And the new integral:
$$\int_{-3+u}^{-2u}\int_v^1\frac13v^2u^{1/2}\,du\,dv$$

But, this not the answer, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: One major problem with your response is that the result of the original integral is a **number** while the result of your integral is a function of u!

Comment: Yeah, i don't understand ):

Comment: @user247327 Help me u.u

Comment: He means that your outer integral has limits (from $-3+u$ to $-2u$) that are functions of $u$, so your result will also be a function of $u$. You need something like the original double integral, where the outer integral has simple numeric limits (from $0$ to $1$) and the inner integral has limits that depend only on the variable of integration in the outer integral ($x$ in this case).

Comment: Your equation for $y$ is incorrect. It should be $y=\frac{2u}{3}+\frac{v}{3}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expression for $y$ in terms of $v$ are not correct. The expressions should be

$$x=\frac u2-\frac v3, \qquad y=\frac{2u}3+\frac v3$$

---

The original, source integral has the outer bounds
$$0\le x\le 1$$
and the inner bounds
$$0\le y\le 1-x$$

Substituting the correct expressions for $x$ and $y$ give
$$0\le\frac u3-\frac v3\le 1, \qquad 0\le\frac{2u}3+\frac v3\le 1-\left(\frac u3-\frac v3\right)$$

Multiplying by three gives
$$0\le u-v\le 3, \qquad 0\le 2u+v \le 3-u+v$$

You should graph those inequalities in the $u$-$v$ plane to see what kind of region you get.

[image]

You see that is a triangle. Now express overall limits on $u$, then limits on $v$ based on the value of $u$.

Comment: I just repeat what I already wrote : you are a very good educator ! Cheers and thanks for this nice answer.

Comment: Excelent Rory, thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1):

The original region of integration is a triangle with vertices $(0,0),\,(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$.

The linear transformation $L(x,y)=(x+y,y-2x)=(u,v)$ will move straight lines to straight lines, so the transformed region will also be a triangle, but its vertices will be $L(0,0)=(0,0),\,L(0,1)=(1,1)$ and $L(1,0)=(1,-2)$.

Draw the triangle of the new region of integration and you will see that the outer limits must go from $u=0$ to $u=1$ and the inner limits must go from the line $v=-2u$ to the line $v=u$.

In other words, it helps to draw the original region of integration and then draw the transformed region. Otherwise you are just manipulating formulas without any understanding of what is going on.

Comment: Thanks, but... how you can see the points $(0,0), (0,1), (1,0)$?

Comment: Remember that the limits on integrals are actually equations. On the original problem the limits on the outer integral are $x=0$ and $x=1$. Those are two vertical lines containing the region of integration between them. The inner limits are the equations $y=0$ and $y=1-x$. The region of integration consists of all points bounded below and above by these two lines and which also lie between the two vertical lines. You will see that it is a triangle with the three vertices $(0,0),\,(0,1)$ and $(1,0).$